# how to strech small base64 image to full screen

Tags: jquery, css

I have one base64 encoded png image.

I wrote following code to strech to full screen

```
[CSS]
background: url(data:image/png;base64,/*---Image base64 code--*/)no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

but didn't works. How can i achive this.

Comment: What selector was used with these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using it on body? if yes, it will be like below.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UVkjT/

```
body
{
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,/*---Image base64 code--*/) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `background`... And all those other values you are feeding to `background-image` **do not apply** to it, but they *do* apply to `background`, if you had given the color parameter. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image

Comment: I missed the small bit at the back. Thanks and answer modified.